Parameter in SQL statement for RDLC report
Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my SQL statement.
*Public variable=year_value_selection
*Report parameter=year_value_parameter
*Select a Year from ComboBox
year_value_selection = Me.ComBxYear.Text (FiscalYear)

Using sql_command As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @year_value_parameter NChar(10) SELECT FiscalYear, Month, Period, Total FROM AnnualFigures WHERE (FiscalYear = @year_value_parameter)", sql_connection)
Dim data_adapter As New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = sql_command}
data_adapter.Fill(annual_data_table)
End Using

Dim value_parameters As IList(Of ReportParameter) = New List(Of ReportParameter)
value_parameters.Add(New ReportParameter("year_value_parameter", year_value_selection))
Me.AnnualReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(value_parameters)

The report is empty with no errors.
I tried inserting the SET command after DECLARE, but got the error 'Invalid column name 'FiscalYear'
Using sql_command As New SqlCommand("DECLARE @year_value_parameter NChar(10) SET @year_value_parameter = FiscalYear SELECT FiscalYear, Month, Period, Total FROM AnnualFigures _ 
            WHERE (FiscalYear = @year_value_parameter)", sql_connection)

Also SET @year_value_parameter = " & " FiscalYear " & "     ('Invalid column name 'FiscalYear')
Also SET @year_value_parameter = 'FiscalYear'           (No error - Blank report)
Me.AnnualReportViewer.RefreshReport()
I have tested the parameter within the report builder by adding the WHERE statement to the SELECT statement, then asigning the desired value to the parameter. This worked fine.
I removed the WHERE statement and removed the parameter value to execute from code. (I have been told that there should only be fields in the Sql statement of the DataSet in the report (is this true?))
Much appreciated.
